# Need to divide a date part in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in my table with these values:

```
PING_TO_ME_20100828_Any87
TO_THESE_D_COLUMN_ENTRY_20200825
TO_THESE_D_20100829_COLUMN_ENTRY
201901_ARE_YOU_TRYING_TO_REACH47
ASK_TO_UOU_201008
```

I need to separate date values in a separate column.

My output should be:

```
20100828
20200825
20100829
201901
201008
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you need to fix your design; *never* store delimited data in your database. Also of those 5 values, I would personally say that the latter 2 (`201901` and `201008`) are not dates; dates are made up of a year, month *and* day; those 2 appear to be missing the day. If they represent dates using 6 digits, not 8, that is a a further problem with your data's integrity.

Comment: Make an effort. Start researching your issue. String splitting is THE MOST COMMON question in SO. And "201008" is not a date. Effectively it seems you want to find all sequences containing numeric characters.

Comment: Some tables that we have without day, that's why the value looks 201901 and 201008 it exists only year and month. As we are working in SQL Server 2012 version

Comment: Any reference links would be great

Comment: I suggest you start by researching [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and splitting on the character "_". That will return a table. From that, what do YOU think you can do to focus on those strings that are composed only of numeric characters? Seems that the [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) operator is useful. Alternatively you could ask your team for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will (and already have) likely get comments about this telling you to fix your design. And while that is likely true...I won't try to pick apart *why* you are doing this, and I'll just give you the answer you came here for.

Your goal is to pick out either an 8 digit string of integers, or a 6 digit string of integers.

Here is one way you could do it:

```sql
SELECT x.y
    , COALESCE(SUBSTRING(x.y, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', x.y), 0), 8)
            , SUBSTRING(x.y, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', x.y), 0), 6))
FROM (
    VALUES  ('PING_TO_ME_20100828_Any87'),
            ('TO_THESE_D_COLUMN_ENTRY_20200825'),
            ('TO_THESE_D_20100829_COLUMN_ENTRY'),
            ('201901_ARE_YOU_TRYING_TO_REACH47'),
            ('ASK_TO_UOU_201008')
) x(y)
```

Explanation:

Since you are looking for both 8 and 6 digit values, you need to check for the longer of the two first. So first I search for the occurrence of a string of 8 integers using:

```sql
NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', x.y), 0)
```

This returns the first position of a string of 8 integers. The reason I wrap it in a `NULLIF()` is because if the value is not found, then `PATINDEX` will return `0`.

I use `NULLIF()` to return `NULL` in that case, essentially indicating nothing was found. If you pass a `NULL` value to `SUBSTRING()` then it also returns `NULL`.

This is all just a nice way of "failing over" to the 6 character string check.

So there I do the same thing again:

```sql
NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', x.y), 0)
```

Except this time, I only repeat `[0-9]` six times. And again, I use the `NULLIF()` trick, so that it returns NULL if no string is found.

Throw that all into `SUBSTRING()` and `COALESCE()` and you've got a function that returns the results you're looking for.

#### Potential downsides

There are a couple down sides to this method.

1. It is not checking for a valid date, it's simply looking for a string of either 8 integers, or 6 integers. It could be `12345678` and it would still detect and return that.
2. If there are strings of integers longer than 8 digits, it will grab only the first 8 characters.
3. If there are multiple occurrences of 6 or 8 character integer strings...it will only return the first one.

There are much more robust ways you could write this, but it all depends on your data and what you need to do.

### Other methods

Another way it could be done depending on which version of SQL Server you are using, is using `STRING_SPLIT()`.

```sql
SELECT x.y, s.[value]
FROM (
    VALUES ('PING_TO_ME_20100828_Any87'),('TO_THESE_D_COLUMN_ENTRY_20200825'),('TO_THESE_D_20100829_COLUMN_ENTRY'),('201901_ARE_YOU_TRYING_TO_REACH47'),('ASK_TO_UOU_201008')
) x(y)
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT [value]
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(x.y, '_')
        WHERE [value] LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
            OR [value] LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    ) s
```

This method handles a couple of the downsides mentioned earlier. For example, it will ONLY return integer strings of length 6 or 8. It will also return ALL integer strings of length 6 or 8 and not just the first one.

And there's other ways to identify the strings as well, like using `ISNUMERIC(x.[value])` or `TRY_CONVERT(int, s.[value])`.

It all depends on how you are using this code...if it's runs fast enough, and it's a one off script, then it really doesn't matter. If it's running for millions of records at a time, then yeah you should play around with other methods.

Comment: That's fine. The point is to provide an answer. Perhaps someone else will somehow come across this and it will help them. Took me only a few minutes to write an answer to a very simple problem that's been up for 10 hours.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked as expected. And many thanks for the explanation about how the query works.

Comment: @PavanKumar great! Always remember to mark answers when one works for you.

Comment: K so I was half right :)